# Is this proof valid? Intersection of complements equals complement of union

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

If $X \subset S\  $ , $Y \subset S , \text{ then } eX \cap eY=e(X \cup Y)$

(where $e$  is "complement")

Proof: if $  x\in S\text{ and } X,Y\subset S,\text{and if } x \not\in X ,\ x \not\in Y \text{ then }x \in eX,eY  \text{ and  } x \in eX\cap eY $

If $x\not\in X,Y \text{ then } x\not\in X\cup Y \text{ hence }x \in e(X\cup Y) $

Side Question:

is this notation ok, $\ x\in eX,eY\ $?

Does that mean x is in $eX$ and also in $eY$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this **proof** valid ? 'complement of'

Comment: What does this have to do with real analysis?

Comment: It's a little hard to follow, but you have the right idea.  You can clean it up by being more explicit about saying, "Assume x is an element of the left side, we show that x is an element of the right side" and then conversely.  The first couple of times I read it through I thought you had only done half of the proof.

Comment: Is $e(X)$ the notation you want to use for the complement or is it the only notation you are able to use in Latex?

Comment: "Is this notation ok"  *any* notation is fine if you define it.  So if you want to use $^{\not\ }X\over{shagoth}$ as your notation of complement you may.  If you are asking if it is clear or something other people have done... no, I've never seen anyone do it and if you hadn't defined it I wouldn't have had any idea what you meant.  But as you *did* define it... it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Oh... maybe you are asking if you can use $x \in A,B$ to mean $x$ is a member of $A$ and that $x$ is a member of $B$.  Well, I guess it probably technically you are supposed to write $x \in A; x\in B$ but.... I and everyone I know would consider $x\in A, B$ just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the proof is correct.
The question about notation, seems to be somehow ambiguous, i mean the notation, you can just use $x\in eX\cap eY$.

Comment: No, I don't think that it is correct. Where did he prove "if $ x \in eX\cap eY$ then $x \in e(X\cup Y)$"?

Comment: @miracle173 when they said "if $x\not\in X,Y$ then $x\not\in X\cup Y$ so therefore $x\in e(X\cup Y)$"

Comment: @miracle173 He/She is using ambiguous notation, but if you take the time to translate it into a correct one, you'll see it is right. When he/she says $s\notin X,Y$ it means x is neither in X nor in Y.

Answer (score 0):

No.

To prove

- $A$ if and only if $B$

you have to  prove

- if $A$ then $B$ and if $B$ then $A$

you proved

- if $C$ then $A$ and if $C$ then $B$

where $A$ is $x \in eX\cap eY$, $B$ is $x \in eX\cap eY$ and $C$ is $x \not\in X ,\ x \not\in Y$.

So you have to prove

- if $ x \in eX\cap eY$ then $x \in e(X\cup Y)$

and

- if $x \in e(X\cup Y)$ then $ x \in eX\cap eY$

As far as I can see you proved

- if $ x \not\in X ,\ x \not\in Y$ then $ x \in eX\cap eY $

and

- If $ x \not\in X ,\ x \not\in Y$ then $x \in e(X\cup Y) $

Comment: I think that the user tried to prove the two implications you talk about; the first line of his proof is the effort of trying $e(X \cup Y) \subseteq eX \cap eY$, while the second line corresponds to $eX \cap eY \subseteq e(X \cup Y) $.

Comment: I think I was not clear. I wanted to show that for every $x\ $ out side of $\ X,Y\ $ ..both those statement are true.. so if they are true for every element.. they prove the original statement.

Comment: @ttz: if you prove that for every $x$ outside if $X,Y$ both those statements ($x \in eX\cap eY$ , $x \in e(X\cup Y)$) are true then you haven't proved that both statements are equivalent. For example for every  $x$ outside if $X,Y$ the statements  $x \in eX$ and $x \in eY$ are true, but both statements are not equivalent.

Comment: @Amelia Maybe the user tried to prove this but I think the user didn't. "if C then B" is related to "if A then B" because both if-then-constructs have the same conclusion B and "if C then A" is related to ""if B then A", but nevertheless they are different.